# How to disconnect iCloud photo storage, without losing all my photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

This is probably a duplicate, and if so I apologize.

Right now my phones aren't backing up because my free 5 Gigabyte iCloud account is completely full of pictures.  I need to upgrade a phone, and that requires a working backup of the old one, so the situation is now critical.

I *think* I just want to disable iCloud photo storage on both phones.  But when I try to turn off "iCloud Photos", I get a prompt saying

> Do you want to download a copy of your iCloud Photos to this iPhone?

No, I don't.  but I have two choices:

> Remove from iPhone

No, I don't want to remove anything from this phone, except the connection that's also uploading everything to iCloud.

> Download Photos & Videos

No, I don't want to download anything to this phone.  Every picture I've taken on this phone is also downloaded to my Mac for long-term storage.

I tried choosing "Remove from iPhone" anyway, and it gives me a confirmation saying:

> 898 photos and videos will be removed from this iPhone. These photos and videos will remain in iCloud Photos.

No! No, no, no!  That's the *opposite* of what I want!  I want to keep them on the phone and delete them from iCloud!  How do I do that?

(Am I reading that message correctly?  While turning *off* the sync-with-iCloud feature, it's really going to delete the copies -- which in my case are the originals -- from the phone?)

I've read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222067/how-do-i-disable-icloud-without-losing-all-my-photos) which seems to match mine, but I think its answer is out of date, as I can't find the dialog it references on my phone.

Comment: If you have the means it might be easier to upgrade the iCloud account for one month. Otherwise, you need to ensure that all your photos are fully downloaded onto your Mac **before** you disable iCloud Photo Library on all devices and then delete the photos on iCloud.com.

Comment: It's basically what the linked answer says, even though the dialogs may be different nowadays.

Comment: @nohillside But the dialog strongly suggests that the action is going to *delete all the photos of my phone also*.  That's what I'm most worried and uncertain about.  (Why would it do that?)

Comment: Do you use Photos on your Mac to store your pictures, or are they just in your own managed folders? Depending on your answer I may have a couple of workflows, not too dissimilar to *nohillside*'s suggestion

Comment: @AndyGriffiths It's sort of both.  I download pictures from my phone using Photos, and then export them all as JPEGs into "my own managed folders".  So redundant copies remain in the Photos library, and I haven't figured out how to safely delete those, either.

Comment: If the original are on the phone, you need to select the "Download Photos & Videos" option. This will only download images which are not on your phone yet (or only in reduced quality).

Comment: Ty. I'll reply later. @nohillside That's worked into my answer.

Comment: @nohillside I have two phones.  Perhaps half of the photos in iCloud are from one phone, half from the other.  Are you saying that if I turn off "sync to iCloud" on phone A, I will have to download to it all photos uploaded to iCloud from phone B?

Comment: @SteveSummit One more question? Is the gist of the problem that you don't have enough iCloud space to store a backup of phone A, and then restore to phone B? Have you tried initialising phone B by doing a local phone to phone copy over your local network? The last time I changed phones that worked marvellously and took minutes. No iCloud backups necessary. My long complicated answer that even I'm now having trouble following may not be necessary.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Thanks for your concern. The immediate problem is the transfer, and I thought the only way to do that was via iCloud backup, I hadn't heard of this "phone to phone copy over local network" thing, so thanks for that tip.  But I was also using this as an impetus to solve my iCloud space problem.  I don't intend to store every photo I've ever taken in iCloud, so I don't see a need to purchase extra storage, but I *would* like my phones to be able to back themselves up there, which they'll never be able to do if photos are constantly soaking up all available space.

Comment: iCloud Photo Library isn't a backup.  Provide for backing up your photos, and then this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll summarise in an answer

Comment: @MarcWilson I have two things (a) phone backup and (b) iCloud photo library competing for my 5 gig of iCloud space.  I need to turn off and delete (b) so I can use more of that 5 gig for (a).  Sorry if I'm using terminology incorrectly.

Comment: If you have two phones connected to the same iCloud account, all photos are already available on both. ICloud Photo Library is a syncing solution after all.

Comment: @nohillside You say that as if it's obvious, but I think a big part of my problem is that I'm oblivious to it: I don't need it, I never asked for it,  I don't understand it, it's causing me problems and confusion, and because I don't understand it I'm stuck, and because everyone else thinks it's so obvious their answers keep whooshing over my head. :-\

Comment: IIRC iCloud Photos gets enabled by default on phones. That's why you weren't aware of it. It justifies Apple giving you 5GB for free to start with. "The first hit is always free..." ;-)

Comment: Fair point, Steve, sorry for implying that things are obvious when they are not.

Answer (score 2):

#### Maintaining the Status Quo in a manageable way

I think your options boil down to either buying more space (even a very usable 50GB only costs me 79p a month) for longer term flexibility or managing your photos thru your macOS iCloud Photos Library to reduce your cloud usage.

This can be done by exporting originals as you are currently doing, or by the use of a 3rd party utility such as PowerPhotos to export to a non-iCloud Photos library on your Mac. You can then delete them from the macOS iCloud Photos library and the deletes will propagate up to iCloud. Or as nohillside originally pointed out, they can be deleted through the iCloud Photos website. In both cases, make sure that Recently Deleted is cleared out once you're sure.

And of course, as has just been pointed out, iCloud storage should not be treated as a backup, so a reliable Time Machine backup of your Mac will also be a good idea.

As for the phone restoration issue, a new phone can be restored over a local Bluetooth connection from and old one. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216

#### Severing phone and iCloud photos

If you make sure you have all the iCloud photos synced to the phone before switching off `Settings | Photos | iCloud Photos`, then it will not prompt you re. downloading when you do, and all the photos remain on the phone. Similarly if you do the same in macOS Photos, then the photos remain on the Mac.

What it's actually doing, even though it isn't particularly clear, is asking you how attached you are to the photos on your phone. If you want to keep them, then it knows that low-quality space savers may be present on the phone, and it is ensuring that the originals get downloaded to the phone.. Or if you aren't bothered, it asks permission to get rid completely.

Managing photos in iCloud is completely separate to that above. To remove the photos from iCloud but leave on your phone:

- On the Mac: `Photos | Preferences | iCloud | Download Originals to this Mac (Tick)`. Monitor this to completion in the Photos app, at the bottom of the `Library`.
- On the iPhone: `Settings | Photos | Download and Keep Originals (Tick)` Monitor this to completion in the Photos app at the bottom of `Recents`.
- On the Mac, duplicate the ~/Photos/Photos Library.photoslibrary (or however your iCloud enabled library is named). On an APFS system this will take seconds.
- Verify the copied library is **not** iCloud enabled by opening it and checking `Photos | Preferences | iCloud` states "iCloud features for Photos are only available in the System Photo Library"
- Run a Time Machine backup to ensure both versions are safe
- Disable iCloud Photos on iPhone: `Settings | Photos | iCloud Photos (Off)`. All photos will remain on the phone. If all photos are not currently on the phone then that is what causes it to prompt.
- Then delete the photos through macOS Photos using the iCloud enabled library, or via the website. They will be removed from iCloud, but remain on your phone.

Future photos taken on the phone will not end up in iCloud, so if you want to transfer them to your Mac you will have to import to macOS Photos, or use the Image Capture utility, both with the phone connected via USB.

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  One clarification: it's *iPhone* backups I'm trying to reserve iCloud storage space for, not Mac backups.  I keep my Mac backed up by completely different means; that's not the issue.

Comment: Yes, you need both. Manage your iCloud space to allow more room for phone backup. My TM backup comment was just a standard thing for others looking for the similar answer in the future.

Comment: Right, but my fundamental problem is that I am completely unable to manage my iCloud space.  Right now it's full of pictures that I don't want and don't need.  But there's no way to delete them without also deleting them off of phones.  And there's no way to sever the connection between my phones and iCloud.  If I leave that connection open, every picture I ever take will upload to iCloud, reducing the space I want to keep clear for backups.  If I sever that connection, it says it's going to delete all the pictures from my phone.  I can't win.

Comment: For now I think I'm going to (1) use Bluetooth to copy data to the new phone (thanks eversomuch for that tip!), and then (2) find time to go to an Apple store and ask them to (a) sever the connection, (b) delete all photos from iCloud, but (c) keep all photos currently on both phones.  I wouldn't have thought a+b+c would be so difficult, but apparently it is.

Comment: Or maybe I should just pay Apple for enough iCloud space for every photo I'll ever take, even though I never intend to access or manage them there, but just to make this problem go away, since it might end up being cheaper than the aggravation involved in solving the problem properly.  But that'd be a deeply unsatisfying solution.  (Sorry for the annoyed-sounding tone: I am certainly not annoyed at you, and I do appreciate your help.)

Comment: That TM backup actually containing the photos would depend on "download originals" (or whatever it's called, I have no use for Photos.app) being set.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the reason you can't delete them without deleting them from your phone is because they're not downloaded to your phone. If you have optimize storage enabled, when you disable iCloud Storage it deletes the undownloaded images from  your phone.

Comment: @Ezekiel So I think you're saying that the scary prompt "898 photos and videos will be removed from this iPhone" does *not*, in fact, mean that 898 photos and videos will be deleted from this iPhone.  Perhaps 898 placeholders or symbolic links will be deleted from this iPhone.  Perhaps some photos of videos that were not originally taken on this phone, that were autodownloaded ("synched") onto this phone, will be deleted.  But — perhaps — some other number of photos, that *were* originally taken by this phone, will not be deleted.  I'd be fine with that — if I could be sure.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths *What it's actually doing, even though it isn't particularly clear, is asking you how attached you are to the photos on your phone*  And it's less clear than that because, I think, there are two kinds of photos on my phone, some I'm attached to and some I'm not.  I'm very attached to the ones I took on that phone, that I might or might not have downloaded or archived elsewhere.  I'm not at all attached to photos that were automatically "synched" to that phone from elsewhere — I never asked for that; I never realized that was happening.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the photos it's asking to delete are precisely the ones I'm not attached to, and that even if I say "yes", the ones I *am* attached to will remain.  If I were sure about this, I could say "yes" to that prompt with a clear conscience.  As it is, I think I'd better double-check that every photo on both phones has, in fact, been downloaded to my Mac.

Comment: A wise move. Hope it works out for you.